# clr-namesapce errors in WPF (renamed namespace)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

Edit: It seems like its just a bug. If someone wants to go into details, feel free to get more details.

I am having a weird problem. Initially things were working fine. I remember I declared namespace as:

```xml
x:Class="SePSI.MainWindow"        
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SePSI;assembly=SePSI"
```

But now, I get error that says:

`Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'SePSI' that is not included in the assembly`.

In fact, I opened old projects, all of them having same errors. [EDIT: Well, other projects are working fine now.]

I am using vs2010. Should I re-install VS?

What might be wrong?

EDIT: More information, I changed names of namespaces, and as far as I think I changed everywhere. I made a new project, where xmlns namespace work fine, but then I changed name of namespaces, and same error their.

I made exact same copy of this project, and it works fine there. I am just curious now what went wrong with old file.

Comment: Are you sure that the custom namespace is declared correctly? Try something like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SePSI;assembly=SePSI"`...

Comment: yeah, that was a silly typo. main problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

When you delcare a namespace in xaml it uses two kind of stratergies for resoling names.

Resolve the object from the same project just wired with namespaces. like.

`xmlns:local="clr-namespace;myproject"`

other way of using namespaces into xaml which is refring other assemblies  these assemblies must be included into project.

```
 xmlns:xceed="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended""
```

twist here your namespace and assembly name may be differ as you may have the assembly name as SePSI but the namespace inside the project are chagned.

and the last one is using custom name spaceing like

```
xmlns:tk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

so you have used the assembly namespacing. make sure you have included that assembliy.

Comment: ;?? clr-namespace;myproject??

Comment: try with xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SePSI" only. as i see you have included the same assembly name in which you are working.  if you add assembly name the render will look for another assembly named SePSI.

Comment: tried both. nothing yet. as i said, i made exact same copy of code here, it works in another file.

Comment: is this SaPSI is diffrent assembly or the same one.

Comment: humm do one think use find all command and search for the namespace keyword this will list down all namespace from your project and then match them into you namespace importings